# What is the efficient way to find common elements of ListBuffer[List[String]]?

Tags: scala

I have a `ListBuffer[List[String]]`. I want to find the common elements among the lists.

Sample input:

```
ListBuffer[List["a", "b", "c", "d"], List["a", "c", "e", "f"], List["a", "c", "g"]]
```

Output:

```
List["a", "c"]
```

I am doing the following, but it is not efficient and taking time for larger lists.

```
val _length = _listBuffer.length
val _flattenList = _listBuffer.flatten
val _commonValues = _flattenList.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size)
  .filter({ case (x, y) => y == _length })
  .keys
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are dealing with sequences, this operation is bound to have a complexity (in the worst case scenario) proportional to the sum of individual items within each nested list.

You can, however, terminate early when you reach a point where you know that the common elements of the items explored so far is empty:

```
import scala.collection.mutable
import scala.annotation.tailrec

val buffer = mutable.ListBuffer(List("a", "b", "c", "d"),
                                List("a", "c", "e", "f"),
                                List("a", "c", "g"))

def dups[X](xss: Seq[Seq[X]]): Seq[X] = {
  @tailrec
  def loop(xss: Seq[Seq[X]], dup: Set[X]): Seq[X] =
    xss match {
      case _ if dup.isEmpty || xss.isEmpty => dup.toSeq
      case head +: tail                    => loop(tail, dup intersect head.toSet)
    }
  if (xss.isEmpty) return Seq.empty[X]
  else loop(xss.tail, xss.head.toSet)
}

println(dups(buffer))
```

You can play around with this code [on Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/CzsXJr1lRLu2xbHDYbqchA).

You can verify this property by rewriting the logic to work on iterators and trying to feed an infinite iterator to it:

```
import scala.collection.mutable
import scala.annotation.tailrec

val buffer = mutable.ListBuffer(List("a", "b", "c", "d"),
                                List("a", "c", "e", "f"),
                                List("a", "c", "g"))

def dups[X](xss: Iterator[Seq[X]]): Seq[X] = {
  @tailrec
  def loop(dup: Seq[X], xss: Iterator[Seq[X]]): Seq[X] =
    if (dup.isEmpty || !xss.hasNext) dup
    else loop(dup intersect xss.next, xss)
  if (!xss.hasNext) return Seq.empty[X]
  else loop(Seq(xss.next: _*), xss)
}

println(dups(buffer.iterator))
println(dups(buffer.iterator ++ Iterator.single(Seq()) ++ Iterator.continually(Seq("a", "c"))))
```

You can play around with this code too [on Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/6APpipSUQOqLgHHivjFk7Q).

Both implementations are stack safe (checked statically by the compiler through the `@tailrec` annotation).

The worst case scenario will still have the same complexity.

Depending on your data you may be willing to use some other approach. If you are willing to trade some time complexity for some space complexity, you can copy to and from `Set`s, which are ideal for deduplication:

```
import scala.collection.mutable

val buffer = mutable.ListBuffer(List("a", "b", "c", "d"),
                                List("a", "c", "e", "f"),
                                List("a", "c", "g"))

def dups[X](xss: Seq[Seq[X]]): Seq[X] =
  xss.view.map(_.toSet).reduceOption(_ intersect _).getOrElse(Set.empty[X]).toSeq

println(dups(buffer))
```

This third example is available [on Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/p3ezYPlTRCu5xm4Qk9lX1A) as well.

Time-wise this approach could work better in certain conditions, at the expense of memory usage (as we are copying your items to a different data structure). Of course you should measure and tune your choice according to the problem at hand.

---

As a last example, you can use both approaches at once (if you see an actual improvement by using `Set`s for your use case) as in the following snippet (which is, as usual, available [on Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/QV4bj0mCT9KrCIu3ocl7fg)):

```
import scala.collection.mutable
import scala.annotation.tailrec

val buffer = mutable.ListBuffer(List("a", "b", "c", "d"),
                                List("a", "c", "e", "f"),
                                List("a", "c", "g"))

def dups[X](xss: Seq[Seq[X]]): Seq[X] = {
  @tailrec
  def loop(xss: Seq[Seq[X]], dup: Set[X]): Seq[X] =
    xss match {
      case _ if dup.isEmpty || xss.isEmpty => dup.toSeq
      case head +: tail                    => loop(tail, dup intersect head.toSet)
    }
  if (xss.isEmpty) return Seq.empty[X]
  else loop(xss.tail, xss.head.toSet)
}

println(dups(buffer))
```

Answer (score 7):

One of the ways to solve is to apply reduction to the `ListBuffer`, intersecting the lists inside the buffer:

```
val buffer = ListBuffer(List("a", "b", "c", "d"), List("a", "c", "e", "f"), List("a", "c", "g"))

val result = buffer.reduce{ _.intersect(_) }
println(result)

// List(a, c)
```